# Can I link a user's app-scoped user id back to his global id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

The facebook api 2.0 has a new app scoped user id.
I  have an app that is using api 1.0.
I know it's backward compatible as in the the old users would still have their original global user id,
but once they remove the app from their app page and connect to the app again after we upgraded they'll get a new app scoped user id.

So the question is, can I use a user's app scoped user id to trace back or link to his global user id? Or the other way around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> This change is backwards-compatible for anyone who has logged into
>   your app at any point in the past.

to mean that user IDs will stay the same even if they remove and re-add the app later.

That said, there is no official way to map global user IDs to app-scoped IDs (I think that's the point, so you can't collect a bunch of user IDs in one app and use them for nefarious purposes in another app)

However, as of right now when I fetch `/v2.2/{global-user-id}` it gives me back an object that contains the app-scoped ID as part of the `link` field:

```
{
  "id": "{global-user-id}",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app-scoped-user-id}/",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "updated_time": "2015-01-26T23:10:43+0000"
}
```